# Positioning canvas with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, html, dom, canvas

I'm creating an drawing application with HTML5 canvas but is having problems with positioning.

I have a div where I dynamically put the canvas. The div has a top div and a bottom div and I want to place the canvas in the middle. As it is now the canvas overlaps the top div and therefore I want to move it down. I have tried styling the canvas (position: absolut, top: 40) but nothing happens. How can I accomplish this?

```js
$('<canvas/>', {
  'id': 'paint',
}).appendTo('#box');

var theCanvas = document.getElementById('paint');
theCanvas.width  = 420;
theCanvas.height = 300;
```

The div looks like this:

```
-----------------
     top div       
-----------------


    canvas


-----------------
    bottom div
-----------------
```

Styling for the divs:

```
#box {
  position: absolute;
  left:50px;
  top: 60px;  
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.topDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bottomDiv {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

The top div and bottom div is inside #box.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the following: What styles are applied to "#box", what styles are applied to the top div, what styles are applied to the bottom div. Please also confirm: Are top div and bottom div inside #box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a couple of assumptions as to exactly what you're trying to accomplish.  Based upon what you I think you want to do, which I assume is have a box that contains two div's, and a canvas (and can be anywhere on the screen, potentially), I mocked up the html as:

```
<div id="box">
    <div class="topDiv">
        this is the top div
    </div>
    <div class="bottomDiv">
        this is the bottom div
    </div>
</div>
```

And, I'd suggest changing your javascript so you insert your canvas before the bottomDiv.

```
$('<canvas/>', {
    'id': 'paint',
}).insertBefore('#box .bottomDiv');
```

And changing your class styling on bottomDiv and topDiv so that they are `position: relative`.  This should accomplish what you're looking for.  Basically the #box controls the position of the group, and the top and bottom div's stay fixed in that group of controls.

Here's a jsFiddle with some border colors to show where the boxes are: http://jsfiddle.net/fordlover49/HKtn5/

Answer (score 0):

You may simply need to apply CSS property `position: relative` to `#box`, but without more details, it's difficult to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Whats wrong with:

```
<style>
#top{Height:40px; }
#bottom{Height:40px;}

</style>

<script>
  var theCanvas = document.getElementById('paint');
  theCanvas.width  = 420;
  theCanvas.height = 300;
</script>

<div id='top'></div>
<div id='paint'></div>
<div id='bottom'><//div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you style your div:s or canvas:es to have absolute positioning or negative margins (or something similar) this HTML with default CSS (div {display: block;}) will do just what you're after:

```
<div>Top</div>
<canvas></canvas>
<div>Bottom</div>
```

Since that doesn't seem to be working for you there must be other code that makes them overlap.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/xRfPq/